# File History vs Backup & Restore

Tags: windows-8, windows-backup

What is the difference between Backup & Restore that was present on Windows 7 and the "File History" feature on Windows 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File history keeps multiple copies of files in a backup location where they can be easily accessed via the properties>file history menu or via direct access to storage location.

Backup and Restore saves a single incremental backup to a location. Backup and Restore can also save a complete system image (note: not *quite* complete). You can use the system image to restore your computer to a previous state. As far as I know you can only use a backup to restore files while on the Windows DVD not file history.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to store a complete system image using File History so that I can restore back to a particular date and time? Or is it just versions of individual files?

Comment: As far as I have seen, no. You could use a combo like I do. I use file history and make regular backups. Although it does use a lot more space it is the easiest solution for me. Have a look at this: http://lifehacker.com/5958865/how-to-use-windows-8s-new-file-history-backup-aka-time-machine-for-windows